# ¿Si no es posible instanciar una clase abstracta, cómo llamaría a esto?

Tags: java

Bien, tengo una duda al respecto y seguro que es fácil de responder. ahí va:
Si tengo la clase:

```
public abstract class Borrame {
    public String nombre = "Borrado";
}
```

y después en el método main() hago:

```
Borrame b = new Borrame(){};
System.out.println(b.nombre);
```

"Esto no da error y crea un objeto de la clase abstracta"

Yo consideraría que he creado un objeto de la clase abstracta y por lo tanto la he instanciado, así que yo debo tener un error pq en todos sitios e incluso Oracle dice que no se puede instanciar. Entonces lo que yo he hecho se debe llamar de otra manera y ahí debe estar mi error.
¿Me pueden ayudar a explicarlo, gracias?

Comment: ¿Estás ejecutando ese código en algún lugar? Porque así como lo tienes no te debe compilar. Y no, no se puede instanciar una clase abstracta. ¿Tiene algún sentido esa clase abstracta o solamente estás experimentando?

Comment: sí claro, he puesto un pequeño texto que dice:
y después en el método main() hago:

Comment: Hola, en realidad estas creando una **clase anónima** en tu código. No puedo escribir una respuesta ahora pero puedes buscarlo. Saludos.

Comment: Cierto @LucasRox ese fue mi error a la hora de explicarme lo que pasaba y más abajo YORS me lo explicó con más detalle. Gracias

Answer (score 5, accepted):

aquí sucede lo siguiente,
una clase abstracta no se puede instanciar, existe la posibilidad de crearle un constructor pero este solo sería usado para que las clases que hereden de ella, usen dicho constructor, como viste en la página de oracle, no se puede instanciar, todo bien ahí, por lo tanto en tu código no podrías hacer algo como

```
Borrame b = new Borrame(); //sin las llaves
System.out.println(b.nombre);
```

Sencillamente esto anterior, no compilaría, pero sí puedes hacer algo cómo esto

```
abstract class BorrameConstructor {
    public String nombre = "Borrado";
    public BorrameConstructor(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    abstract void hazAlgo();

}

class BorrameHijo extends BorrameConstructor {
    public BorrameHijo(){
        super("BorrandoHijo");
    }
    public void hazAlgo(){
       System.out.println("hago algo");
    }
}
```

y en tu main algo como esto

```
BorrameConstructor b = new BorrameHijo();
System.out.println(b.nombre);
b.hazAlgo();
```

Luego, existe otro concepto en java que son las clases anónimas, donde puedes crear una clase anónima que extienda de una clase abstracta (o implemente de una interfaz) mientras vas escribiendo tu código, puedes crear una clase anónima, para ello defines una variable e "instancias" la clase usando un constructor seguido agregas las llaves y vas implementando los métodos abstractos que la clase (o interfaz) tenga.

por eso puedes realizar en tu código algo como esto:

```
Borrame b = new Borrame(){}; //se crea una clase anónima que hereda de borrame y se instancia en b
System.out.println(b.nombre); //usa el objeto de la clase anonima heredada de Borrame
BorrameConstructor b2 = new BorrameConstructor("Borrado Anonimo"){
//crea la clase anonima y se instancia en b2

   //se tiene que sobreescribir el método abstracto
   public void hazAlgo() {
     System.out.println("hago algo anonimamente");
   }
};

System.out.println(b2.nombre);//imprime Borrado Anonimo
b2.hazAlgo(); //imprime hago algo anonimamente
```

En tu caso, como Borrame no tiene algún método que implementar, con agregar las llaves {} crearía una implementación de la clase anónima y su posterior instanciación.

Espero te haya ayudado, es la forma como crear una clase anónima, sirve igual para las interfaces, con la diferencia de que no existe un constructor con parámetros como lo tiene la clase anónima.

Puedes revisar más acerca de las clases anónimas, dado que esto es parte de lo que ahora son los lambdas.

Comment: Si, gracias por toda la ayuda me ha quedado super claro. Gracias a la fenomenal comunidad de desarrolladores siempre dispuestos a que crecer juntos.

Answer (score 3):

Resulta que `b instanceof Borrame` da verdadero, pero si hace `b.getClass()` ya no te devuelve Borrame. Devuelve la ubicacion seguido de $1.

En mi caso javaApplication$1,

Por lo que me da la impresión que te crea una clase auxiliar que hedera de Borrame.

```
  System.out.print(b instanceof Borrame);   
  System.out.println( b.getClass());
```

Lo que al final veo es que java te está creando una clase en tiempo de ejecución. Al poner el {} le estás pidiendo que cree el objeto abstracto pero te da una clase hija vacia como si de una conversion se tratase.
Haciendo internamente `javaApplication$1 extends Borrame`.

Comment: Genial, es que efectivamente con el "hack" de las {} creo una clase anónima, pero aunque parece sale de un new de la propia clase abstracta en realidad no es ella, lo que cómo tu dices es una "pirula" que hace por detrás Java, puesto que cómo no me debía dejar crear una instancia de la clase abstracta y al final lo hace cómo tu dices. No es una verdadera instancia de la clase abstracta, sino cómo dices de una hija anónima.
Era un poco lioso explicarlo y me lo has dejado bien claro. A no ser que alguien aporte otra explicación con detalle, esta me viene genial. Muchas Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Hasta donde yo se en java no se pueden crear objetos de clases abstractas, si le quitas el abstract te funcionará ademas si no tienes ningun metodo abstracto de q te sirve?, es lo que creo y es bajo mis conocimientos jajja todavia estoy en primero de carrera. y el Borrame(){}; (el constructor cuando lo llamas), no sería mejor poner Borrame(); a secas sin los "{}"?

Comment: la cuestión es que eso no da error y crea el objeto. Por supuesto eso no hace nada es sólo un código de ejemplo. Lo del constructor con las llaves es para que me deje crear el objeto, ya que se sería como hacerlo de manera anónima ya que al ser abstracta no se deja, pero la cuestión es que con ese "hack" obtengo un objeto de la clase abstracta
Gracias por contestar